# Fetch request fails when I send POST request from React app to a Flask API

Tags: reactjs, web-deployment, flask-restful, flask-cors

I'm pretty sure I've done everything correctly. Included 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' in my response headers and everything.

I've browsed some other posts on StackOverflow and everything seems to be in line with all the suggestions there.

Here's the thing: when I run it on my local machine it works perfectly fine. But when I run it on the server (Ubuntu 16) with host=0.0.0.0 as in app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5000) I keep getting

ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED:
[image: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED]

My response headers in the back-end:
[image: My response headers in the back-end]

The fetch in React:
[image: The fetch in React]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use flask-cors to solve this.

`from flask_cors import cross_origin`

And before your endpoint, add:

`@cross_origin('localhost')`

So it will look something like this:

```
@app.route('your_route')
@cross_origin('the origin you need')
def something():
```